# How do I use different data set for collapsed row data in AG grid

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

We currently have two sets of data that needed to be displayed in the grid. The grid needs to have a row group with data (dataset A) when collapsed and then each individual row within that group (dataset B) when expanded. Is there a way to do this without using a grid within a grid? The columns are the same when expanded and collapsed.

Comment: It's not really clear what your problem is, try to add more information. Right now your question reads like this: "I have a problem and I want to solve it without using the two normal solutions".